# Force sklearn IterativeImputer to continue iterating

Tags: python, scikit-learn, imputation

I am using sklearn's IterativeImputer with a RandomForestRegressor to impute my data. Considering Random Forests do not need their data scaled, I cannot give the argument "tol" a value, because it will not be in any meaningful units. How do I nonetheless force IterativeImputer to continue iterating?

Answer (score 0):

To figure this out, we should compute a given rank order, so we can calculate the distance between each node and the rank order. I could guess that as our goal is a list of ranking, the value for. The RandomForestRegressor you using has one huge exception: if there are no nonzero values for the first and last moments it should return True. And indeed it does. The first moment is if one excludes the endpoints which have no data.
Finally, the last moment is when the centroid is derived from all data:
I got my data. I tried to use randomForestRegressor

Answer (score 0):

Does the imputer actually stop?  From [this issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/14338) it sounds like it shouldn't, and setting `tol` won't do much.  Anyway, from the documentation of `max_iter`, the stopping criterion is:

```py
max(abs(X_t - X_{t-1}))/max(abs(X[known_vals])) < tol
```

which does take the feature scale into account (in a rough way), so I think it's safe to think of a fixed `tol` even when features have very different scales.